# Downloading file from page using JSF

Tags: jsf

Is there a way to automate downloading of files in page which uses JSF?

I need to download file based on parameters I choose from drop-down menu and calendar. After that, if I understand correctly, server redirects to right download file or generates file.
If I had a direct link based on parameters, I could use small bash/batch script, but I don't have the link so I need some help.

Comment: You need to be more clear on the functional requirement. The part which is unclear is what kind of file it is and where it originates. Is it a static file which is stored in public web content? Or is it stored outside public web content? Or is it stored in a database? Or is it an in-memory file? Or is it a dynamically generated file? If the latter, what API/tool is supposed to generate the file content? Etc. I also wonder how exactly JavaScript is related to this. How exactly did you expect that JavaScript would be helpful in some way?

Comment: Maybe it'll be better if I show. This is the page: 
http://www.msci.com/products/indices/performance.html 
In the bottom of table there is link - Download results:Regional /Regional & Country.
This is the thing I need to get  - xls file based on parameters above the table.
I don't know how it's stored or generated.
JS was mentioned just because it's often used together with jsf. But yes, it's not directly related.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is JSF1.2 with richfaces, then refer this url

[Download log file using JSF application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8877794/download-log-file-using-jsf-application)

i hope you will get some idea.